# Disable filesystem browsing in Fennec

Tags: android, mozilla, android-source, fennec

I'm developing custom AOSP 4.4 firmware for custom Android device.
I'm using Fennec (Firefox for Android) as default browser.
My custom AOSP does not pass Android Compatibility Testsuit.

Link to test: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/cts/tests/tests/security/src/android/security/cts/BrowserTest.java

testBrowserPrivateDataAccess()  test fails.
This test checks if browser is able to explore root filesystem and download files from it. To access root filesystem I enter file:/// in Fennec browser. I am able to download system applications, from /system/app folder, etc. Such behavior is not desirable.

I have checked this issue on fresh Firefox and Firefox Beta from PlayStore. I was able to reproduce it only on tablets (LG G Pad 8.3, Nexus 10), not reproducible on (Nexus 4, HTC Sensation, Nexus 5).

I can build Fennec by myself, from sources. Can anyone help me how I can disable file exploring through Fennec?

Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that you can access to root file system is that you install your fennec like system application. I have the same issue now. As I understand there is possible solutions:

1. Install fennec different way.
2. Add some changes to fennec sources.
3. Disable this functionality in some config files.

Hope these items helps you.
I will continue my investigation if i will find solution I will let you know.